# Rails multiple record entries on one submit button in different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-entries

I have two models named **race_timing** and **members** having one to many relationship.
Member's model contain member details of number of students and race_timing model will contain the corresponding timings of each student for any event.

In my race_timing model i want to submit the timings of students in slots of 8 i.e at one time on one submit button 8 records can be updated where timing is taken in single text field and updated in 3 different columns minute,second and microsecond for each member.

I have seen all other posts and tried but only last entry was done in the database.

Can anyone please suggest how this can be done?

Comment: Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms and implement

Comment: I already tried that but still only last entry was done in database @Arup Rakshit

Comment: I didn't get you.. last entry was done means ?

Comment: for e.g we have 8 text fields for 8 members to add timings but when i click the submit button only the last entry was updated in the database

Comment: I got the issue. because you have all the text fields have the same name. And that's why it is happening. Again The link I gave tyou is the way to create a form when you have has_many assocations.. Please go though it.. You will be fine.

Comment: I already tried that but still could not find any solution. still only last entry goes into the database @ArupRakshit

Comment: Show your code what have you tried and didn't work.